# Meteor Collection is not sent after upgrade to 0.5.9

Tags: meteor

For some reason after upgrading to 0.5.9 I'm having the issue where server side seems to send everything correctly, however client side says it has received nothing.

//server:

```
Meteor.publish("orders", function (ordersQueryParams) {
    console.log("orders publish: " + JSON.stringify(ordersQueryParams));
    if (this.userId && ordersQueryParams){
        console.log("orders collection: " + Orders.find({"customer._id": this.userId}, ordersQueryParams).count());
        return Orders.find({"customer._id": this.userId}, ordersQueryParams);
    }
});
```

//client:

```
var ordersPreferences = {
                table: {
                    size: 10
                },
                query: {
                    sort: {createdDate:-1},
                    skip : 0,
                    limit : 10
                }
            };
Session.set("ordersPreferences", ordersPreferences);
Meteor.autorun(function(){
   var ordersPreferences = Session.get("ordersPreferences");
   console.log('subscribing to orders');
   Meteor.subscribe("orders", ordersPreferences.query);
}
```

//both:

```
Orders = new Meteor.Collection("orders");
Deps.autorun(function(){
    if (Meteor.isServer)
        console.log("on server orders count is " + Orders.find().count());
    if (Meteor.isClient)
        console.log("on client orders count is " + Orders.find().count());
});
```

Server log:

```
on server orders count is 26
orders publish: {"sort":{"createdDate":-1},"skip":0,"limit":10}
orders collection: 26
```

Client log:

```
subscribing to orders
on client orders count is 0
```

Why server says there are **26** docs, however client insists on **0**?

It's driving me nuts :(

Comment: Was this working on 0.5.8?

Comment: @Prashant It was working on 0.5.7

Comment: I've noticed that Meteor.autorun() is removed from the docs, can this be the issue?

Comment: @KristofferK according to [Meteor's changelist](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/History.md#v058) both `Meteor.autorun` and `Deps.autorun` should be working (at least for now)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem:

I was "waiting" for my `Meteor.user()` to become available and had this `autorun`:

```
Meteor.autorun(function(handle){
            var ordersPage = new OrdersPage();
            if (Meteor.user()) {
                ordersPage.init();
                ordersPage.autorun();
                handle.stop();
            }
            });
        if (Meteor.user()) {
            return "orders";
        }
```

Once the `Meteor.user()` was found this function does not need to run, hence I had `handle.stop()`.
Apparently from 0.5.9 `handle.stop()` stops not only the immediate `autorun` but everything underneath as well (including the collections).

Might be a bug introduced in Meteor... or might be a new feature.